# How to connect ITK with VTK?

Tags: visualization, vtk, image-segmentation, medical, itk

I'm reading DICOM series using itk and converting them into VTK for visualization purposes. Even though I manage to visualize DICOM series in 3 different windows with 3 different orientations (XY, XZ and YZ) I can't even click on the windows. When I click or try to change the slice viewed, my code gives an access violation error. I'm using ImageViewer2 to visualize the slices. A file called itkVTKImageExportBase.cxx is opened when I try to find out what the error is. The lines referred to are:

```
void VTKImageExportBase::UpdateInformationCallbackFunction(void* userData)
{
  static_cast<VTKImageExportBase*>
    (userData)->UpdateInformationCallback();
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
typedef itk::VTKImageExport< ImageType > ExportFilterType;
    ExportFilterType::Pointer itkExporter = ExportFilterType::New(); 
    itkExporter->SetInput( reader->GetOutput() );


    // Create the vtkImageImport and connect it to the itk::VTKImageExport instance.
    vtkImageImport* vtkImporter = vtkImageImport::New();  
    ConnectPipelines(itkExporter, vtkImporter);


    pViewerXY->SetInput(vtkImporter->GetOutput());
    pViewerXY->SetSlice(3);
    pViewerXY->SetSliceOrientationToXY();
    pViewerXY->SetupInteractor(m_pVTKWindow_1);
    pViewerXY->UpdateDisplayExtent();
    m_pVTKWindow_1->AddObserver(vtkCommand::KeyPressEvent, m_pVTKWindow_1_CallbackCommand);
    m_pVTKWindow_1->Update();

    pViewerXZ->SetInput (vtkImporter->GetOutput());
    pViewerXZ->SetSliceOrientationToXZ();
    pViewerXZ->SetupInteractor(m_pVTKWindow_2);
    pViewerXZ->UpdateDisplayExtent();
    m_pVTKWindow_2->AddObserver(vtkCommand::KeyPressEvent, m_pVTKWindow_2_CallbackCommand);
    m_pVTKWindow_2->Update();

    pViewerYZ->SetInput (vtkImporter->GetOutput());
    pViewerYZ->SetSliceOrientationToYZ();
    pViewerYZ->SetupInteractor(m_pVTKWindow_3);
    pViewerYZ->UpdateDisplayExtent();
    m_pVTKWindow_3->AddObserver(vtkCommand::KeyPressEvent, m_pVTKWindow_3_CallbackCommand);
    m_pVTKWindow_3->Update();
```

pViewerXX windows are imageviewer2 objects whereas m_pVTKWindow_X refers to wxVTK objects to use in wxWidgets GUI package.

Optional: My exporter and importer are as given below:

```
template <typename ITK_Exporter, typename VTK_Importer>
void ConnectPipelines(ITK_Exporter exporter, VTK_Importer* importer)
{
  importer->SetUpdateInformationCallback(exporter->GetUpdateInformationCallback());
  importer->SetPipelineModifiedCallback(exporter->GetPipelineModifiedCallback());
  importer->SetWholeExtentCallback(exporter->GetWholeExtentCallback());
  importer->SetSpacingCallback(exporter->GetSpacingCallback());
  importer->SetOriginCallback(exporter->GetOriginCallback());
  importer->SetScalarTypeCallback(exporter->GetScalarTypeCallback());
  importer->SetNumberOfComponentsCallback(exporter->GetNumberOfComponentsCallback());
  importer->SetPropagateUpdateExtentCallback(exporter->GetPropagateUpdateExtentCallback());
  importer->SetUpdateDataCallback(exporter->GetUpdateDataCallback());
  importer->SetDataExtentCallback(exporter->GetDataExtentCallback());
  importer->SetBufferPointerCallback(exporter->GetBufferPointerCallback());
  importer->SetCallbackUserData(exporter->GetCallbackUserData());
}
/**
 * This function will connect the given vtkImageExport filter to
 * the given itk::VTKImageImport filter.
 */
template <typename VTK_Exporter, typename ITK_Importer>
void ConnectPipelines(VTK_Exporter* exporter, ITK_Importer importer)
{
  importer->SetUpdateInformationCallback(exporter->GetUpdateInformationCallback());
  importer->SetPipelineModifiedCallback(exporter->GetPipelineModifiedCallback());
  importer->SetWholeExtentCallback(exporter->GetWholeExtentCallback());
  importer->SetSpacingCallback(exporter->GetSpacingCallback());
  importer->SetOriginCallback(exporter->GetOriginCallback());
  importer->SetScalarTypeCallback(exporter->GetScalarTypeCallback());
  importer->SetNumberOfComponentsCallback(exporter->GetNumberOfComponentsCallback());
  importer->SetPropagateUpdateExtentCallback(exporter->GetPropagateUpdateExtentCallback());
  importer->SetUpdateDataCallback(exporter->GetUpdateDataCallback());
  importer->SetDataExtentCallback(exporter->GetDataExtentCallback());
  importer->SetBufferPointerCallback(exporter->GetBufferPointerCallback());
  importer->SetCallbackUserData(exporter->GetCallbackUserData());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact answer to your question, but have you considered using one of the common medical image processing frameworks? There are a couple of them like MITK ([mitk.org](http://mitk.org)) or Slicer3D ([slicer.org](http://slicer.org)). They do a great job of linking together ITK, VTK and a sophisticated GUI Framework like QT (in the MITK case).

I have worked a long time in medical image processing and used MITK extensively. In my opinion, using a medical image processing framework really helps you focus on your real image processing problems, rather than trying to build processing/visualization pipelines for different types of visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [InsightApplications](http://itk.org/gitweb?p=ITKApps.git;a=summary), there are two methods:

1. The same as you tried, which is [here](http://itk.org/gitweb?p=ITKApps.git;a=blob;f=ConnectVTKITK/ConnectVTKITK.h;h=6e72757a9350b78382dbaa3140db712d96e21aa6;hb=HEAD), or
2. [This one](http://itk.org/gitweb?p=ITKApps.git;a=blob;f=vtkITK/Common/vtkITKImageToImageFilter.h;h=35e189bffa3686af75b3c2829d56cc8d4211aeb9;hb=HEAD), which creates a pipeline object that can be connected on both sides. We're actually using this, and it works out quite well for us. You can copy this class into your code and use it.

There are some interesting usage examples in there too. Take a look at them and see if you can modify anything for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in the [ITKVTkGlue](http://itk.org/Insight/Doxygen/html/group__ITKVtkGlue.html) module can be used to convert an ITK image to in a pipeline.  See [the tests](http://itk.org/gitweb?p=ITK.git;a=tree;f=Modules/Bridge/VtkGlue/test;h=7cdcbc4df16617632a8eff8d0b33e630ee3c563a;hb=HEAD) for examples of how the classes are applied.